# Create anonymous class instance from generic and override methods

Tags: java, class, generics

I am trying to create an (anonymous) instance of `T` from the `Class<T extends Foo>` object passed to the method. I know how to use `newInstance` on the `Class` object to create an instance of `T`, but I want to override a method from `Foo`.
I have been searching for solutions for quite a while, but I couldn't figure it out.

I have the following set up:

```
public class Foo {

  public void doStuff() {
    // do stuff
  }

}
```

I want to do the following:

```
public <T extends Foo> T getFoo(final Class<T> clazz) {
  // How?
  return new T() {
    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
      // do other stuff
    }
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this? Is there any workaround?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: This is not a duplicate of the suggested question. As I stated I already know how to use `newInstance` which was also provided as an answer in that question. I need to override a method from `Foo` which is not answered in the suggested question.

Comment: You would have to create byte-code dynamically to be able to do that. Not saying it's impossible, but it's definitely not a trivial task, and there's probably a much better/simpler way of achieveing what you want. What concrete problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Priv, we could build a proxy from `clazz` and tune `InvocationHandler`, but `clazz` should be an interface

Comment: No, I am trying to override an existing method.

Comment: @Andrew you can still post your answer. Other people may also find it useful.

Comment: What I don't quite understand is why you need to override the same method every time, and have the same implementation every time, when you instantiate an instance of a subclass of `Foo`. Why not simply do this in the sub-class definition (which you need to do anyway) and return `clazz.newInstance()`? Provided that you don't need anything other than the default constructor.

Comment: If I add the overridden method in every subclass I have to copy the code every time.

Comment: @SeverityOne From the looks of it, this mechanism would allow you to instantiate "normal" subclass instances by just using `new` or `newInstance`, and also allow you to create "altered" instances by using `getFoo` (i.e. a mixin system). Your suggestion won't allow this.

Comment: What kind of stuff would be include in that ```doStuff``` override. Would it only access elements in ```Foo``` or would it call methods and access fields in the enclosing class that defines ```getFoo```?

Comment: only stuff from Foo